# How to display mathematical formula in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, math, formula

I'm planning to build an APP which helps the less developed area share the same learning resources.

Displaying mathematical formula is a key feature of this APP. Is there any opensource components which allows the app displaying the formula in React Native?

Comment: [react-native-mathjax](https://github.com/calvinkei/react-native-mathjax) does what you are after

Comment: https://medium.com/age-of-awareness/math-symbols-for-react-native-dcc93a4cfa7e just take a look